# Can 'to be gone' be used in this sentence?

Tags: phrase-usage

I am translating a text, and I am not sure whether I can use **'to be gone'** in this sentence meaning 'not left', 'there weren't any of those items left', 'they run out of those things'? 
Is there a better way to say it?

**At 11 am, all cooked food, a large part of cold snacks and water, milk, plates, glasses were gone.**

Comment: This is perfectly acceptable.  What is it that you had a question about specifically?

Comment: Thank you David! I was not sure whether such usage was acceptable. I have used 'to be gone' with the meaning 'not left' conversationally now and then, but I am not a native speaker and was not sure whether it would be fully acceptable in a written form. I found some examples with '..all gone' (e.g., the food in the fridge was all gone), but couldn't find anywhere whether just 'be...gone' was fine in this meaning. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **glasses were gone**

Here  gone  is  an adjective meaning **no longer there**

The use of  gone in that  sense is  idiomatic even  in writing.

Here is  a link  which  explains  the  usage  better.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gone